# Cannot drop the table '#MultipleNonFinTran', because it does not exist in the system catalog. Transaction context in use by another session.n

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have below issue in sql server 2000 reports, The report fails to open by throwing the below error. Can any body

Query execution failed for data set 'NonFinTran'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) Get Online Help

Cannot drop the table '#NonFinTran', because it does not exist in the system catalog. Cannot drop the table '#MultipleNonFinTran', because it does not exist in the system catalog. Transaction context in use by another session.

Comment: +1 for the awesome table name haha.